# How to duplicate an paragraph with one changed string

Tags: perl, duplicate

I'm looking for something that could copy a paragraph, change the user and insert it in same file.

file before:

```
user1
  this is only
  a test of 
  a lovely idea

user2
  this user shhould
  be copied

user3
  who has an
  idea for
  my problem
```

file after (`user2` was searched,copied and inserted as `user4`):

```
user1
  this is only
  a test of 
  a lovely idea

user2
  this user shhould
  be copied

user3
  who has an
  idea for
  my problem

user4
  this user shhould
  be copied
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/perl
#
use strict;

local $/="\n\n";

my $match = shift @ARGV;
my $subst = shift @ARGV;
my $save;

while (defined (my $paragraph = <>))
{
    $paragraph =~ s/\n+$//;
    $paragraph .= "\n";

    my $user = ($paragraph =~ m/(\w+)\n/)[0];
    if ($match eq $user)
    {
        $save = $paragraph;
        $save =~ s/\b$user\b/$subst/g
    };

    print "$paragraph\n"
}
print "$save" if defined $save;
exit 0
```

Use it like this

```
script.pl user2 user4 <file
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

```
@(collect)
@name
@  (collect)
@line
@  (last)

@  (end)
@  (maybe)
@    (bind name @[*args* 1])
@    (bind cname @[*args* 2])
@    (bind cline line)
@  (end)
@(end)
@(merge name name cname)
@(merge line line cline)
@(output)
@  (repeat)
@name
@    (repeat)
@line
@    (end)

@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr insert.txr data user2 user4
user1
  this is only
  a test of
  a lovely idea

user2
  this user shhould
  be copied

user3
  who has an
  idea for
  my problem

user4
  this user shhould
  be copied
```

Awk state machine:

```
BEGIN       { split(ed,kv,","); }
1
$0 ~ kv[1]  { copy = 1; next }
copy        { lines = lines ? lines "\n" $0 : $0 }
/^$/        { if (copy) have = 1; copy = 0; }
END         { if (have) { print ""; print kv[2] ; print lines } }
```

Run (output as before):

```
$ awk -f insert.awk -v ed=user2,user4 data
user1
  this is only
  a test of
  a lovely idea

user2
  this user shhould
  be copied

user3
  who has an
  idea for
  my problem

user4
  this user shhould
  be copied
```

TXR Awk, equivalent logic. Lines are accumulated in an actual list data structure, rather than string. The list serves as a Boolean, indicating true if not empty so we don't need the `have` flag. We have direct access to remaining arguments after the data file.

```
(awk
  (:inputs [*args* 0])
  (:let lines copy)
  (t)
  ((equal rec [*args* 1]) (set copy t) (next))
  (copy (push rec lines))
  ((equal rec "") (set copy nil))
  (:end (when lines
          (put-line) (put-line [*args* 2]) (tprint (nreverse lines)))))
```

Run (output as before):

```
$ txr insert.tl data user2 user4
```

Comment: +1 for dog-fooding TXR, which I've never heard of until now. But I reckon my `perl` is more readable :-) (I like your FSM for `awk`, too.)